# Heroku doesn't commit changes to SQLAlchemy databse after scheduler finishes the work

Tags: flask, heroku, sqlalchemy, scheduler

I am running Flask app on heroku and planning to implement scheduler. Everything seemed to work on local server, but on Heroku it never submits changes to database. I run it on the free tier. Here is the code:

```
from app import app, db, SteamProfiles, hours_calculator
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def daily_users_update():
    for profile in SteamProfiles.query:
        clear_id = profile.steam_profile_id.replace("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/", "")
        status, hours = hours_calculator(clear_id)
        profile.hours_in_2_weeks = hours
        print(profile.hours_in_2_weeks)
        db.session.commit()

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(daily_users_update, "interval", seconds=30)
scheduler.start()
```

If I run it through heroku terminal, I see that it does update hours, but doesn't the database. Besides, there are no errors during runtime, just logs from the execution.

Here is the procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app

clock: python updater.py
```

Don't understand what's wrong with it, so any suggestions will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does the API work when deployed on your local system?

Comment: Yep, I export it locally and on heroku it's in env variables